# Are Window Messages "Reliable"?

Tags: windows, winapi, window-messages

This is somewhat of a general question regarding Windows programming:

Are Window messages "reliable"?

For *example* (these are just *examples*):

- Can you be *certain* that a `WM_MOUSEMOVE` will happen before a cursor enters your screen?
- Can you be *certain* that you will get a `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message if a device is inserted?
- Can you be *certain* that you will receive a `WM_KILLFOCUS` message if your window loses focus?

Or, in other words: Can you be *certain* that you'll get the appropriate message at the appropriate times, or do you always have to code defensively in case that, *somehow*, you might miss a message for no apparently documented reason?

---

#### Example:

- It is **guaranteed** (AFAIK) that a file system filter driver will not "miss" a file operation or change notification.
- By contrast, it is **not** guaranteed that [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465.aspx) will not miss a notification. In fact, it can miss quite a few if its buffer overflows.

#### Note:

I am **not** talking about a situation against an adversary (e.g. someone hijacking your window procedure or installing a hook/filter); that would pretty much invalidate any guarantee. I'm only asking about obscure situations that could really happen even if no one meant anything bad intentionally, like if some random buffer overflows, if someone uses `SendInput`, etc., *assuming you have control of your own code*.

Comment: This is NOT what "reliable" means.  "Reliable" means that you can be certain that either the message was successfully delivered OR an error is reported to the sender, messages cannot be lost silently.

Comment: In general, no you can't. For specific messages, yes you can.

Comment: @Ben: That's not what *I* meant by "reliable". ;) I'll put an example to illustrate my point.

Comment: The window message queue also has a maximum length (from [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944.aspx): "There is a limit of 10,000 posted messages per message queue."), `PostMessage` can fail if the queue is full.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot be certain that a given message will be delivered in a specific order.  Here are a couple of reasons why not

- Messages can be sent progamatically and this can be used to simulate "impossible" scenarios like a `WM_KEYUP` followed by a `WM_KEYDOWN`.
- Another routine could sub-class your window and selectively intercept messages and not send them on to your `WNDPROC`

It's best to code defensively around any scenarios where ordering is important